# NSArray to CALayerArray

Tags: iphone, memory, nsarray

I have a problem and I cannot figure out what is going on

I have a tableview and I have a property names newsData.
I setup everything and its working fine!
Then in the simulator I call memory warning to see how the app is working.
I can see that the tableview is being released and when I call back the viewdidload I can see that this array is now class CALayerArray!!!
When I try to access it my program crashes!

What is going on?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you reallocated tableview within the viewdidload call? After you released it you need to do that. You might want to set your tableView nil after releasing it, in order to avoid the crashes (This still requires you to reallocate and initialize the tableView after you released it!)

```
 [tableView release];
 tableView = nil;
```

Clearification: I dont mean, you need to set any object nil after you released it! But after releasing it, you should be aware of the object being already released!

Comment: I would not recommend setting per default all released objects to nil. The good thing about NOT setting it to nil is that your app crashes if you try to reference this released object. If you had set it to nil it will not crash but will still not work. That makes troubleshooting quite difficult.

Comment: I think we are both correct in a way. Setting nil SHOULD not be needed. If you release the object, you shouldn't use it anymore anyways. If you still want to use it, you should overthink your code.

Comment: I totally agree. I just wanted to avoid @auslander to automatically set every released object to nil.

Comment: See MCRelease for the correct compromise IMO. http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/dealloc.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the nil. I do not release the tableview, I have an NSArray in the controller. When I simulate memory warning in the sim, automatic the tableview controller is being released. After that the array I have is CALayerArray!!! When I try to set the values again it crashes!

Comment: I do not know why! But I did what you told me set the newsData to nil after the release and now its working 100% correct!!! Although I do not believe I do something wrong with my code that could cause this problem! But thanks for the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes for this depending on the code. First, I'm confused when you say "I have a tableview and I have a property names newsData." What object does `newsData` belong to? Did you subclass `UITableView`, or do you mean this is an ivar of your `UITableViewDataSource`?

What is `newsData`? This sounds like it should be an `NSData`, but are you saying that it's an `NSArray`?

You should first audit everywhere you assign `newsData`. In most cases I would say you're assigning it to something that does not return an `NSArray`. I doubt that in this case because `CALayerArray` is private. This looks more like you're accessing memory that's being used for something else. I would check your memory warning code and your `viewDidUnload:` code and run the static analyzer as a start.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have a tableview controller and there I the NSArray newsData that holds objects. My main code is working fine! no leaks and everything nice and smooth. The problem is after I trigger the memory warning. After that the newsData is of class CALayerArray. and when I try to access it it crashes!!